# Integral involving $\log$'s

Tags: integration, logarithms, hypergeometric-function

how can I integrate:
$$ \int \frac{\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}dx$$
I did in the following way but it seems to my kind sketchy.

$\text{li}(x)$ the logarithmic integral,$\gamma$ the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\text{F}\left|\begin{array}{l}a_{1}...a_{p}\\b_{1}...b_{q}\end{array} ;z\right|$ the hypergeometric function.

$\frac{d}{dx} \text{li}(x)\log(\log(x)) =\frac{\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}+\frac{\text{li}(x)}{x \log(x)}$

$\text{li}(x)=\gamma+\log(\log(x))+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)^{k}}{k! k}$

$\int \frac{\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}dx=\text{li}(x)\log(\log(x)) - \int \frac{\text{li}(x)}{x \log(x)}dx+c=$

$=\log(\log(x))\Big(\text{li}(x)-\gamma -\frac{1}{2}\log(\log(x)) \Big) -\int (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)^{k}}{k! k})\frac{dx}{x \log(x)}+c=$

$=\log(\log(x))\Big(\text{li}(x)-\gamma -\frac{1}{2}\log(\log(x)) \Big) -\log(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)^{k}}{k! (k+1)^{3}}+c.$

$ \ $

> $$  \int \frac{\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}dx=\log(\log(x))\Big(\text{li}(x)-\gamma -\frac{1}{2}\log(\log(x)) \Big) -\log(x)\text{F}\left|\begin{array}{l}1,1,1\\2,2,2\end{array} ;\log(x)\right|+c.$$

is it ok? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have started using $x=e^t$ to make
$$I=\int \frac{\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}\,dx=\int \frac{e^t \log (t)}{t}\,dt$$ Now, using the expansion of $e^t$ we have
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int\frac{t^{n-1} \log (t)}{n!}\,dt=\int \frac{\log (t)}{t}\,dt+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\frac{t^{n-1} \log (t)}{n!}\,dt$$

For the first integral
$$\int \frac{\log (t)}{t}\,dt=\frac{\log ^2(t)}{2}$$ and for the other
$$J_n=\int\frac{t^{n-1} \log (t)}{n!}\,dt=\frac{t^n (n \log (t)-1)}{n^2 n!}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_n=\log (t) (\text{Ei}(t)-\log (t)-\gamma )-t \, _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;t)$$

Comment: that is way more elegant

Comment: @PatrickDanzi. Thanks ! When I see a logarithm, my first reaction is to do this.